# Starting threads in a loop passing array elements to each

Tags: c#, arrays, multithreading, indexoutofboundsexception, ref

i start 4 threads in a loop. each thread gets a reference to an array element to write the result.

But on the line where i create each thread, i get a `System.IndexOutOfRangeException`. I'm amazed that the index "i" is going out of range.

here is an example:

```
void ThreadsStarter()
{
    double[] data = new double[4];

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        Thread my_thread = new Thread(() => Work(data[i]));
        my_thread.Start();
    }
}

void Work(double data)
{
}
```

Why this is happening?

Comment: You are ["closing over the loop variable"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx)

Comment: I've removed `ref` from your sample/title as unrelated to the question - feel free to edit/rollback. Note `ref` is generally hard to use/understand, especially when you start using more flexible collections like `List<double>` instead of `Array`. Try to avoid `ref` - i.e. in this case `Tuple.Create(data, i)` could be an option (obviously created before lambda to avoid problem you have now).

Comment: thanks. now i also know the name of that construction (closures/lambdas). i do try to avoid ref. i will consider using tuples instead, this seems cleaner. that's a good article Blorgbeard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a common error: i gets evaluated when threads starts, which happens after the loop has ended. Make a temp, assign i to it, and use temp instead of i in your lambda to fix the issue:

```
void ThreadsStarter()
{
    double[] data = new double[4];

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        var temp = i;
        Thread my_thread = new Thread(() => Work(ref data[temp]));
        my_thread.Start();
    }
}

void Work(ref double data)
{
}
```

Comment: This works because when you recreate a temp variable, the compiler detects that the closure is "attached" to a different variable on every loop pass and will generate a "**new** DisplayClass()" code (which encapsulates the closure) inside every pass. Without temp variable it'll use the same DisplayClass (which holds a member of the i variable) from within all loop passes. (Similar to the code that c# 5 generates for a foreach loop - see an example [here](http://aakinshin.net/en/blog/dotnet/closures/#the-foreach-loop)).